# Package Experience Site integrated with ISV app

Tags: managed-package, isv, experience-cloud

Many ISV providers with apps on the Salesforce AppExvchange make use of Experience Sites / Communities. Even Salesforce themselves. But only to talk to their customers.

**What if I want to allow the subscribers of my Managed Package to leverage a ready-made, packaged site template that is integrated with my app?**

I am thinking about the following use cases and scenarios:

1. Subscribers use my app to manage custom objects and model the relationship with their own customers (stored as Leads, Contacts, Accounts)
2. They use Standard Salesforce features like Email Campaigns to engage with them
3. They want to extend the collaboration beyond email and its limitations (amounts per day)
4. They go on a Setup page of my app, which unpacks and helps them configure an Experience site for their customers. This setup automates part of the cumbersome Setup of Domains and Sites
5. It activates Chatter on some of the app Custom Objects and allows customers to join this discussion from the Experience Site.
6. Inside the app, there is Report and Dashboards that show engagement with the community

**Has this been done? Can this be done? How can this be done? I know that Sites cannot be fully packaged. I know that Setup cannot be fully automated. I am looking for some tips and tricks by somebody who has tries this. Successful or not.**

Comment: What I've done isn't quite as you suggest. Packaging of a digital experience in a managed package is, according to the conversations I had on the partner forums a couple of years back, a complete no-no nightmare. But packaging one as an unlocked 2GP that layers on top of a managed package works really well, as per my [Q&A](/questions/347145/how-do-i-package-an-upgradable-experience-builder-site).